# Password hashing: is this enough for a wap application?

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash, passwords

First of all, I believe it needs to be pointed out: I am making an application for mobile phones which usually have slow enough internet and thus am in need of a compromise between speed and security.

I will be using the same function (yet different variables used to create the hash, of course) to create users' auto-login cookies and store their passwords.

So far it looks like this:

```
function multiSHA($toSha, $mode=0, $count=100) { //$mode=1 to create cookies with uniqid, or =0 for hashing with externally specified salt (added to $toSha) and static pepper
    $toSha=hash('sha512',$toSha); //so that I know the length of the string below
    if ($mode==0) {
        for ($i=0; $i<$count; ++$i) {
            $p1=hash('sha512',substr($toSha,0,64)); // since I know the length
            $p2=hash('sha512',substr($toSha,64,128));
            $pepper=hash('sha512','This is my static pepper.');
            $toSha=hash('sha512',$p1.$pepper.$p2);
        }
    }
    else {
        for ($i=0; $i<$count; ++$i) {
            $p1=hash('sha512',substr($toSha,0,64));
            $p2=hash('sha512',substr($toSha,64,128));
            $uniqid=hash('sha512',uniqid('This is my static pepper.',true));
            $toSha=hash('sha512',$p1.$uniqid.$p2);
        }
    }
    return $toSha;
}
```

Now, would this be sufficient enough to store password and cookie data? I cannot use, for example, `PBKDF2` as it hogs up **too** much resources, but this one is fairly lightweight. The attacker would not know how many times the `for` loop is repeated and I would also store the cookies in a separate table to do some extra security checks (e.g. user agent).

Also, how many loops should I be prepared to do in order for this to be safe enough **without making my site an easy target for DDOS attacks**?

Comment: These attacks are normally called Brute attacks and DDoS-es are different.

Comment: I was not talking about just gaining access to a user's account; I was talking about causing long-term high load (which `PBKDF2` is guaranteed to do) to the site and making it unavailable.

Comment: How do you want to validate an entered password with the stored salted hash if you don’t store the used salt as well?

Comment: @Limoncello sorry i thought you are curious just about the security. 
from what i can see, hashing 100 times doesn't make a difference. even 3-4 times md5'd hash will take years to decrypt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not an expert in cryptography. Do not attempt to create your own cryptographic constructions, as they will probably be flawed in some subtle way that you don't know enough about crypto to recognize.

At a minimum, your "multiSHA" hashing scheme lacks salting in mode 0, and is non-repeatable (and therefore completely useless) in mode 1.

In any case, the speed/power of the client device has absolutely no bearing on the security of the data encryption that you can and should use on the server side. If you are concerned about PBKDF2 placing an excessive load on the server, apply some form of rate-limiting to login attempts.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean. I am currently using memcache that blocks a user's IP for 15 minutes if they fail to log in 5 times, would that be enough? `EDIT` As for the salt, it is submitted along with the string to be hashed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the guidelines from [OWASP - Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet).

Currently they recommend 64,000 iterations of hashes to the password.  I can't find the reference (I thought it was on OWASP), but I recall seeing recently that the salt should be at least 24 bytes as of 2012.

I think for the moment, 64,000 iterations of SHA-512 with salt should be sufficient for your security.

Edit:  The note about the salt is from OWASP but it appears to have been removed.  The original text was:

> Since we've seen rainbow tables in the wild for all passwords of up to
>   24 characters in size, a salt of at least 24 bytes is the recommended
>   minimum length.

Comment: Thank you for the link and info, reading through some more articles there right now.